# Unhandled exceptions during AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net, elmah

I am trying to implement some sort of handler for unhanded exceptions that occur during AJAX but since I am new I can't seem to get the hang of it. What I have experienced on my test setup is that nothing is returned to the client when an exception occurs. Also, none of these exceptions are being handled by ELMAH.

So this questions has 2 parts:

1. How do I get the server to send back something meaningful, like an error code and message, so that the client can be informed.
2. How can I get ELMAH to log exceptions that happen during an AJAX callback?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not do a try/catch around your server side code and then pass something meaningful back so the client can output the helpful error message?

I'm not sure why ELMAH is not logging your uncaught exception if its occuring server side though. Are you sure its trapping other errors?

Comment: Yes it is trapping other errors, and yes I could do a try catch around all of my code but that does not seem like a good solution to me.

Comment: If you know its possible that a exception is thrown then I'd trap it.

Comment: I have trapped all possible occourances (I think), but I would to have an all round wrapper just in case.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post", url: "/SomeController/SomeAction",
    success: function (data, text) {
        //...
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText);
    }
});
```

Or a  generic handler

```
$(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
});
```